# How to sort firebase getDownloadURL() results with javascript?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

This function is displaying images from firebase urls:

```
function updateTimeline(){
    var ul = document.querySelector("#timeline ul");
    ul.innerHTML = "";
    var db = firebase.database().ref("phoodos/");
    var list = db.orderByChild("timeStamp");
    list.on("child_added", function(child) {
        var selfie = child.val();

        // Retrieve the image file
        var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
        var imageRef = storageRef.child(selfie.path);

        imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
            var li = "<li><figure>";
            li += "<img src='" + url + "' width='100%' alt='Phoodo'>";
            li += "<figcaption>By " + selfie.user + ": " + selfie.timeStamp + "</figcaption>";
            li += "</figure></li>";
            ul.innerHTML += li;
        })
    });
}
```

Results of orderByChild are sorted, but results from getDownloadURL() are not sorted.

How can I sort the images retrieved by getDownloadURL() before adding to my html?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One trick is to insert the HTML in the correct order:

```
var ul = document.querySelector("#timeline ul");
ul.innerHTML = "";
var db = firebase.database().ref("phoodos/");
var list = db.orderByChild("timeStamp");
list.on("child_added", function(child) {
    var selfie = child.val();

    // Retrieve the image file
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();
    var imageRef = storageRef.child(selfie.path);

    var li = document.createElement("li");
    ul.appendChild(li); // this ensures the <li> is in the right order

    imageRef.getDownloadURL().then(function(url){
        var html = "<figure>";
        html += "<img src='" + url + "' width='100%' alt='Phoodo'>";
        html += "<figcaption>By " + selfie.user + ": " + selfie.timeStamp + "</figcaption>";
        html += "</figure>";
        li.innerHTML = html;
    })
});
```

Comment: Brilliant!  Where do I send your check?! I spent 8 hours on this and I read many of your other posts, Frank, and almost messaged you directly.  Thank you so much!

And for the curious who want to know how to reverse the order:

I set the timeStamp to 0 - Date.now()
and stored the images in reverse order using:
object.setWithPriority({...} , 0 - Date.now())

Hope that helps someone.  Cheers!

Comment: Good to hear this solved your problem Richard, and thanks for the edit. :-) Happy hacking!